# mysql: display_name not displaying?

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with this please because I can't see a reason why this isn't working.

I have a mysql query which selects all items in `ptb_reviews` and `ptb_profiles` tables.

I have set `ptb_reviews.from_user_id` to be equal to `ptb_profiles.user_id` 
so now I am wanting to echo out the `display_name` of the `user_id` in `ptb_profiles` that are equal to the `from_user_id` in `ptb_reviews`.

However it won't display the `display_name`, the only way it works is if I echo out the `from_user_id` which gives me the user number rather than the name.

My `ptb_reviews` table looks like this:

```
id  |  from_user_id  | to_user_id  | content |
1           2               5         hello
2           5               6         hi
3           -1              6         hello
```

My 'ptb_profiles' table looks like this:

```
id  |  user_id  |  display_name  |
1         2            jack
2         5            lisa
```

Here's my mysql query:

```
function get_reviews() {
            global $connection;
            global $profile_id;
            $query = "SELECT *
                        FROM ptb_reviews, ptb_profiles
                        WHERE ptb_reviews.to_user_id = \"$profile_id\"
                        AND ptb_reviews.deleted ='0'
                        AND ptb_reviews.approved = '1'
                        AND ptb_reviews.from_user_id = '-1'
                        OR ptb_reviews.from_user_id = ptb_profiles.user_id
                        GROUP BY ptb_reviews.content
                        ORDER BY ptb_reviews.date_added DESC
                        LIMIT 5";
            $reviews_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($query, $connection);
            return $reviews_set;
        }
```

php:

```
  <?php $reviews_set = get_reviews();
    if(mysql_num_rows($reviews_set) > 0) {
    while ($reviews = mysql_fetch_array($reviews_set)) { ?>

<?php echo "{$reviews['display_name']}"; ?>
```

Can someone please show me where I'm going wrong because I can't figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: You should stop using mysql extension and pick up mysqli or pdo. mysql will be deprecated in the near future.

Comment: `mysql_*` ARE depcrecated NOW.

Comment: @MikeBrant then how would i be getting a result for every other column except 'display_name'?

Comment: @HarryMan The fact that mysql functions are depcreated doesn't mean that you can't use them.  They are still usable for backwards compatibility reasons, but you really shouldn't write new code that relies on them.

Comment: @MikeBrant I thought that was in 5.5 which isn't quite ready for production yet... my bad.

Comment: @HarryMan You are grouping by content which allows mysql to pick which display name, user id, etc it wants. You are also letting mysql determine which field to make the relationship to ptb_profiles. You also have an issue in your OR clause.

Comment: @Kevin You are correct in that it is depcreactedas of 5.5.0. I only made the distinction, as for a while the PHP.net documentatoin indicated that the functions were to be deprecated in the future, while they now specifically indicate that deprecation of these functions has been finalized.

Answer (score 0):

First, *don't* use "implicit joins" (`select * from table1, table2 where table1.aField = table2.aField`); Use explicit joins: `select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.aField = table2.aField`.

I suggest some simple steps to ensure yo get what you want. Try everything that follows in your MySQL console (or Workbench or another interface) before implementing it in your PHP project.

Returning all the rows in your tables for a single `to_user_id` with the appropriate filters should be easy.

```
select 
    *
from
    ptb_reviews as r
    inner join ptb_profiles as p on r.from_user_id = p.userId
where
    r.deleted = '0'
    r.approved = '1'
order by
    r.date_added desc
limit 5
```

If this works, then start adding the `where` conditions you need. Try them one by one and when you get what you need, put it in your PHP project

Comment: if you look in his table he actually has a user_id that is equal to -1. Not sure why..